# Cordova ios error building Images.xcassets

Tags: ios, cordova, npm

I've spent a lot of time trying to work this out to no avail.

I udpated cordova and since el capitan my mac now has issues with NPM and cordova.

I got it to install but I have to use sudo for cordova now.

I **tried** the following:

```
sudo cordova platform remove ios
sudo cordova platform add ios
sudo cordova build ios
```

And this gives me the following **output:**

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileAssetCatalog build/emulator/<AppName>.app <AppName>/Images.xcassets
(1 failure)
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/MacUserName/Desktop/<AppName>/<AppName>/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,<AppName>.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,<AppName>,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/MacUserName/Desktop/<AppName>/<AppName>/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/MacUserName/Desktop/<AppName>/<AppName>/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/MacUserName/Desktop/<AppName>/<AppName>/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,<AppName>.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,<AppName>,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/MacUserName/Desktop/<AppName>/<AppName>/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/MacUserName/Desktop/<AppName>/<AppName>/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

Cordova version

```
sudo cordova -v
6.0.0
```

Update:  I'm now running 6.1.1, still the same issue

Cordova iOS platform version

```
sudo cordova platform ios -v
6.1.1
```

Mac Version: 10.11.3

XCode Version:7.2.1

Comment: had the same error. removed and re-added the ios platform then removed icon instructions in config.xml and re-built successfully. no idea how it can manage to generate icons without making them correct size, but somehow, some component in cordova manages to create all the icons the wrong size (1024x1024 in my case). Go team.

Comment: @jimmont I've definitely tried removing the platform and re-adding it many times.  Never any luck

Comment: There are a couple of useful app icon/splash screen builders for cordova: https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-splash and https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-icon

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend using the cordova-icon and cordova-splash npm packages.  This is because you can just put two images in your root, then the commands will work out the rest for you.  They are written by cordova, and you can install using:

```
npm install -g cordova-icon
npm install -g cordova-splash
```

Then just put a 1024x1024 version of your logo as "icon.png" in the project root.  And:

> "The splash screen image should be 2208x2208 px with a center square of
>   about 1200x1200 px. The image may be cropped around the center square."
>
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-splash

Just put an image matching that description in the project root as "splash.png"

Remove any lines in config.xml that specify the images to use for ios, cordova-icon/splash will automatically put them in the correct place with the right names so that xcode will recognize them.

Once you've got that setup, just execute these commands:

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
cordova-icon
cordova-splash
```

Then run your build command.  For me it is:

```
cordova build ios --build-config
```

But you may not have a build config, or need additional params.  If the build fails (make sure you run the command even if you think it will fail - it will set things up) just open the generated workspace in platforms/ios in xcode, clean the project, and build.  That should work.

Comment: Note for a bug: On OSX it was required to also install imagemagick to get cordova-icon or cordova-splash working. The bug I encountered which had to have imagemagick installed [was answered here](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-splash/issues/29). This also required having HomeBrew installed to imagemagick which can be done by typing into the terminal `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` [Which I found on the HomeBrew site here](https://brew.sh/). Hopefully this helps somebody.

Comment: I don't think cordova is as active now that there are arguably better alternatives like Flutter, Xamarin, and React Native for cross platform mobile development.  Coming back to a cordova project, cordova-icon doesn't seem to be working well with updated cordova. (Which in turn wasn't playing well with updated iOS and I had to disable the modern build system)

Answer (score 34):

I managed to fix this issue by:

- removing any icon or splash screen references in the `config.xml` file;
- put a `splash.png` and/or `icon.png` files in the `www/resources` folder of your cordova project; then,
- run the `ionic cordova resources --icon` or `ionic cordova resources --splash` command

this will create all the correct splash/icon files for you and add them to the `config.xml` file.  That warning then goes away.

Hope this works!

Comment: I'm using cordova not ionic, so I can't run "ionic resources" anything

Comment: Thanks, I was having this exact problem.

Comment: @csga5000 You can just use the ionic tools when you're building. You don't have to include the client libraries for this to help.

Comment: @FrodmanG I believe I did somethign like removing configs for icons/splashes, removing/adding my ios platform, and then correcting the configuration of icons/splash.  One thing I'd advise for anyone with similar issues is to open the platform in xcode and check that everything looks right and has valid filepaths in the xcassets file.

Comment: @csga5000 - you can do the same thing with cordova : first install cordova-splash and cordova-icon (`npm install -g cordova-splash cordova-icon`), then create your icon.png and splash.png in the root of your cordova project (ie. the directory above /www), then run them (`cordova-icon ; cordova-splash`) and all the correct icon and splash images will be created in the correct area under /platforms.   (Note that you need ImagicMagic installed).   The iconic commands are just wrapping these same npm modules.

Comment: With v3 of CLI you now run ionic cordova resources --icon and ionic cordova resources --splash

Answer (score 7):

1. Rename Platform/ios
2. on terminal type: `cordova  platform add ios`
3. `cordova build ios`.

worked at my case

Comment: On the second point you got an error. Its cordova platform add ios .

Comment: If 1 suggests renaming the directory platforms/ios I have not tried that.  However, I've tried cordova platform remove ios, instead and this did not resolve the issue.  I've even tried creating a new project and adding that.  The only fix I've found is commenting the line for the logo from the config file and then removing/adding the platform.

Answer (score 4):

For a solo **icon.png** file, the image must be **1024x1024** to get working with a solo `<icon src="icon.png"/>` in the **config.xml**.

I have to this with *cordova-cli 6.5.0*, *cordova-ios 4.5.1* and *xcodebuild 9.0*.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is this documented anywhere or is this an unknown Cordova bug?

Comment: It was 4 years ago, I cannot remember :-S

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I was using `cordova-icon` but my `icon.png` image was not square.

Changing the `icon.png` to a square image and re-doing `cordova-icon` meant that `cordova build ios` now works for me.

Comment: That wasn't my problem, I only found out about cordova-icon a day or two ago actually, and no problems.  But perhaps still useful for some.  Thanks Kris

Answer (score 2):

Ths simple solution that I have tried is to add the correct size of the image 1024x1024

```
   <platform name="ios">
        <icon src="res/icon-1024.png" />
    </platform>
```

Answer (score 1):

After digging into cordova_lib I think it's clear (to me) that cordova is not supposed to resize the icon for you but only copy them if they exist and have the right dimensions.

See this code in cordova-lib\src\cordova\metadata\ios_parser.js:

```js
// See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html
// for launch images sizes reference.
var platformIcons = [
    {dest: 'icon-60.png', width: 60, height: 60},
    {dest: 'icon-60@2x.png', width: 120, height: 120},
    {dest: 'icon-60@3x.png', width: 180, height: 180},
    {dest: 'icon-76.png', width: 76, height: 76},
    {dest: 'icon-76@2x.png', width: 152, height: 152},
    {dest: 'icon-small.png', width: 29, height: 29},
    {dest: 'icon-small@2x.png', width: 58, height: 58},
    {dest: 'icon-40.png', width: 40, height: 40},
    {dest: 'icon-40@2x.png', width: 80, height: 80},
    {dest: 'icon.png', width: 57, height: 57},
    {dest: 'icon@2x.png', width: 114, height: 114},
    {dest: 'icon-72.png', width: 72, height: 72},
    {dest: 'icon-72@2x.png', width: 144, height: 144},
    {dest: 'icon-50.png', width: 50, height: 50},
    {dest: 'icon-50@2x.png', width: 100, height: 100}
];

var destIconsFolder, destSplashFolder;
var xcassetsExists = folderExists(path.join(platformRoot, 'Images.xcassets/'));

if (xcassetsExists) {
    destIconsFolder = 'Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/';
} else {
    destIconsFolder = 'Resources/icons/';
}

platformIcons.forEach(function (item) {
    var icon = icons.getBySize(item.width, item.height) || icons.getDefault();
    if (icon){
        var src = path.join(appRoot, icon.src),
            dest = path.join(platformRoot, destIconsFolder, item.dest);
        events.emit('verbose', 'Copying icon from ' + src + ' to ' + dest);
        shell.cp('-f', src, dest);
    }
});
```

The best option seems to be using a plugin which does the resizing for you with hooks. Check out [Generating iOS and Android icons in Cordova / PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830467/generating-ios-and-android-icons-in-cordova-phonegap) or https://github.com/disusered/cordova-icon-gm for a new more futureproof version of the same plugin (hooks in directories are deprecated in 6.x).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by removing the non-storyboard splash references in config.xml, the newest version of cordova seems to be only using the storyboard ones:

So removed:

```
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
```

And kept only these:

```
        <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone~anyany.png" />
        <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone~comany.png" />
        <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone~comcom.png" />
        <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default@3x~iphone~anyany.png" />
        <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default@3x~iphone~anycom.png" />
        <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default@3x~iphone~comany.png" />
        <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default@2x~ipad~anyany.png" />
        <splash src="res/ios/splash/Default@2x~ipad~comany.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a difficult error.Only thing has to do is remove all lines with

> Images.xcastsets

from

> platform/ios/.xcodeproject

Then remove platform ionic cordova platform rm ios,
Add platform again and build.

> ionic cordova platform add ios
>
> ionic cordova build ios

Comment: I appreciate this may have solved a problem for you but I don't believe this is the solution to the OP as the issue is related to the incorrect, or lack of, suitable icon and splash screen images. I had the same problem and had that error on first build, so at that point there was no platform/ios folder!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP and whilst the accepted answer was correct and helpful there is now an updated (and maintained) resource generator on npm called cordova-res, which replaces cordova-icon and cordova-splash. Also, the required splash screen dimensions have increased. All the details you need are on the [npmjs cordova-res page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-res), from which I have taken the following info.

Install with:

```
npm install -g cordova-res
```

You'll need your icon.png and splash.png (the website says JPEG or PNG) images ready. These need to have the following dimensions:

icon.(png|jpg) must be at least 1024 × 1024px

splash.(png|jpg) must be at least 2732 × 2732px (note the increased size)

Just a little side note about the splash screen. Your image needs to be in the centre of the splash screen so that different rectangular device sized images are generated without cropping your splash screen image. As the accepted answer says, the size of this centre image needs to be about 1200 x 1200px.

Place these images in a resources folder in your project:

```
resources/
├── icon.png
└── splash.png
```

Before you generate the resources it might be worth removing and adding your ios platform (and others if you're building them too) to start with a clean platform folder. I don't know for sure if this is necessary.

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Run the following to generate the resources:

```
$ cordova-res
```

Then you can build your platform:

```
cordova build ios
```

Now all should be OK and hopefully resolved your xcassets error, as it did for me.

Comment: Just wanted to note that this package only works for node >=10.3.0