# Cordova ios build fail "CompileAssetCatalog build"

Tags: ios, cordova

Cordova version 6.1.1
Cordova ios platform version 6.1.1

I am unable to find any solution for the following error

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileAssetCatalog build/emulator/myapp1.app myapp1/Images.xcassets
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/appdev/Desktop/All-Apps/myapp1/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,myapp1.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,myapp1,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/appdev/Desktop/All-Apps/myapp1/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/appdev/Desktop/All-Apps/myapp1/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

Comment: Hey I'm having a similar problem. Mine is related to the splash plugin - as soon as I add the <splash> tags in the config it stops compiling. When I remove the tags I have to remove all plugins and add them again before it'll compile again. Is this the same problem you're having? Because this err 65 has A LOT of causes and it really isn't saying much about what really causes it.

Comment: I've opened a bug for this but it's a bit alarming that this was occurring a year ago. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12733

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095819/cordova-ios-error-building-images-xcassets