# Ionic build fail CompileAssetCatalog

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic 3 and I execute the following command in terminal

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

And now I have this issue

> The following build commands failed:
>           CompileAssetCatalog build/emulator/myapp.app myapp/Images.xcassets

I'm using xcode 11 and default project images

Answer (score 0):

remove any icon or splash screen references in the your `config.xml` file.
put a splash.png and/or icon.png files in the www/resources folder derectory  of your project  then,
run command the

```
ionic cordova resources --icon 
ionic cordova resources --splash
```

find other solutions

[Cordova ios error building Images.xcassets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095819/cordova-ios-error-building-images-xcassets)