# Build commands failed: CompileAssetCatalog - Cordova for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova, command-line-interface

After setting up a fresh Cordova for iOS project trough the CLI this error comes up.

> Build commands failed: CompileAssetCatalog
>   /Users/a/example/example/platforms/ios/build/emulator/Example.app
>   /Users/a/example/example/platforms/ios/Example/Images.xcassets
>
> (1 failure) xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65

- Cordova Version: 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
- Xcode Version: 11.2.1
- macOS Version: 10.15

CLI:

```
cordova create example com.example.app Example
(cd example)
cordova platform add ios 
cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-6-Plus, 9.3"
```

What I tried:
- Clean up build folder
- Update Node/NPM
- Update Xcode

P.S.: Does it make a difference if the .ipa gets build trough the Cordova CLI or from within Xcode?

Comment: what does your build.json look like, if you have one?

Comment: I have one, it looks like this: https://gist.github.com/prof3ssorSt3v3/def4c8a06c0c69af4bd82c69b80f7d8c

Comment: @Tom: Do any of [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095819/cordova-ios-error-building-images-xcassets) work?

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

If you are using cordova 9.0.0, I'm assuming you're also using cordova-ios 5+. In that case, the `"-UseModernBuildSystem=0"` in your `build.json` is no longer necessary. cordova-ios@5 supports the modern build system.

You should also remove the target: `--target="iPhone-6-Plus, 9.3"`. XCode 11 no longer, by default, ships with iOS9 simulators. In fact, you should not specify a target at all, unless necessary.

If you're still facing problems after fixing these two issues, try opening and running your project via XCode, it is likely to provide an improved error log and possible hints to fixes.

Answer (score 0):

there is meny approach that getting resolve exit code 67

1) method 1

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

2) in xcode give your provision profile check

> You need a development provisioning profile on your build machine.
>   Apps can run on the simulator without a profile, but they are required
>   to run on an actual device

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/

3) `cordova platform update ios`

further informations [cordova run with ios error .. Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166175/cordova-run-with-ios-error-error-code-65-for-command-xcodebuild-with-args)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue in Xcode, by creating new
"iOS App Icon". Name it whatever you want, but you must choose it from dropdown in project's settings ie target settings, parameter is "App icons source". Then copy all images via Finder into that folder, and in Xcode
connect(drag&drop) those uncategorised images into placeholders.